# How to do a update of the axis boundaries in SCILAB?

Tags: updating, axes, scilab, boundary

I'm working on a GUI. 
In the GUI, I have a graph, which shows me the results of a measurement file.
If I want to plot another file, I delete the children of the axes and plot the new results. However, the axis boundaries remains the same.

How can I update the boundaries to my new results?
I already tried it with axeshandle.auto_scale = 'on' and xset("wresize",1), but both of the do not work.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to add minimal piece of code to show how you managed to plot your result afayk

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide any example how your gui plots your figure, the first thing that came to me is :

```
// do what you need to have x an y
plot(x,y)
set(gca(),'data_bounds',[min(x),min(y); max(x),max(y)]
```

Also, I suggest to update the `data` field of your graphic entity instead of deleting the whole children.

```
// do what you need to have x an y
set(plothandle,'data',[x,y])
set(gca(),'data_bounds',[min(x),min(y); max(x),max(y)]
```